# Installing hdf5-openmpi-devel in Fedora 23

Tags: hdf5, openmpi, fedora-23

I am trying to install `hdf5-openmpi-devel` in Fedora 23. When I run

```
sudo dnf install hdf5-openmpi-devel
```

I get

```
Last metadata expiration check: 1:12:51 ago on Mon Oct 30 22:53:47 2017.
Package hdf5-openmpi-devel-1.8.15-10.patch1.fc23.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

But when I check with ldconfig, I don't see any openmpi files:

```
rg@supersg: ldconfig -p | grep hdf5
libhdf5hl_fortran.so.10 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libhdf5hl_fortran.so.10
libhdf5_hl_cpp.so.10 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libhdf5_hl_cpp.so.10
libhdf5_hl.so.10 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libhdf5_hl.so.10
libhdf5_fortran.so.10 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libhdf5_fortran.so.10
libhdf5_cpp.so.10 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libhdf5_cpp.so.10
libhdf5.so.10 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib64/libhdf5.so.10
```

Any ideas how to install `hdf5-openmpi-devel` in Fedora 23?

Answer (score 1):

The libs are in `/usr/lib64/openmpi/lib`

```
ldd /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libhdf5.so.8
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffa2d3f000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007fade3235000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fade3030000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fade2d2e000)
    libmpi.so.12 => /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so.12 (0x00007fade2a4a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fade282d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fade246a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000559a79df2000)
    libopen-rte.so.12 => /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libopen-rte.so.12 (0x00007fade21ee000)
    libopen-pal.so.13 => /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/libopen-pal.so.13 (0x00007fade1f49000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fade1d41000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fade1b3e000)
    libhwloc.so.5 => /lib64/libhwloc.so.5 (0x00007fade1900000)
    libnuma.so.1 => /lib64/libnuma.so.1 (0x00007fade16f4000)
    libpciaccess.so.0 => /lib64/libpciaccess.so.0 (0x00007fade14e9000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007fade117f000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fade0f69000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fade0d42000)
```

they should be automatically picked if you use the MPI wrappers `mpicc`, `mpifort` and friends

Comment: HDF5 adds h5cc, etc. which should set things up for HDF5 and MPI.